# How to get info from object on click

Tags: javascript

So i made this object and i'm appending to the html. I would like to make a js function that would give me the info from the object upon clicking the element. So when i click element named car it would give me the name car in js.

```
 var ItemCollection =

[
    {

        Name: 'IVY PARK SHOES',
        Price: 160,
        Picture: 'https://assets.adidas.com/images/w'
    },
    {

        Name: 'JOGGER SHOES',
        Price: 160,
        Picture: 'https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_840,h_840,f_'
    },
    {

        Name: 'ULTRABOOST SHOES',
        Price: 200,
        Picture: 'https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_840,h_840,f_auto,q'
    },
    {

        Name: 'NITE SHOES',
        Price: 130,
        Picture: 'https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_840,h_840,f_a'
    },
    ];
```

i know the one bellow will give me the items index but i'd like it to give me name/price or picture. Also the it doesn't have to be alert the alert is just to see if it works.

```
var g = document.getElementById('Collection');
for (var i = 0, len = g.children.length; i < len; i++) {

    (function(index){
         g.children[i].onclick = function(){
             alert(index);
         }
    })(i);

}
```

Comment: how does your html look like?

Comment: `alert(ItemCollection[index].Name);` will give you `Name` similarly `ItemCollection[index].Price` for `Price` and `ItemCollection[index].Picture` for `Picture`. What is stopping you to do this ?

Comment: thank you it worked if you post it as an answer i can mark it as a right answer.